# How to nest client component NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, components

I'm new to NextJS and react and I'm trying to understand client components.

I have a client component called `Form.jsx` like

```
export default function FormHome() {
   ... tons of client side javascript function ...
   const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
   
function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    startTransition(async () => {
      ... other code ...

        setOpen(true);
      });
    });
  }


   if(isDesktop) {
      return (
      <Form {...form}>
        ... a very long block of javascript that interacts with the function above...
        <Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        ... some other code ...
        </Dialog>
      </Form>
      );
   }
   
      return (
      <Form {...form}>
        ... the same very long block of javascript as above that interacts with the function above...
        <Drawer open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        ... some other code ...
        </Drawer>
        <AlertDialog open={openAlert} onOpenChange={setOpenAlert}>
        </AlertDialog>
      </Form>
      );
}
```

I have then a `page.tsx` with just

```
export default function Home() {
  return <Form />;
}
```

Is there a way, in the same `Form.jsx` client component to nest the various `<Drawer>`, `<Dialog>` and so on but, passing to them variable (like in my case I need to pass `{open}` and `{setOpen}`)

Comment: im not sure im getting your question here. can you clearify/simplify/try other way to ask the question? do you want to have the same child components to be rendered inside Form.jsx, but you want to be able to get data without passing it as props?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to extract some of your JSX code into a separate component. It could be done like this:

```
// name this component whatever you want
function DrawerWrapper(props) {
  return (
    <Drawer open={props.open} onOpenChange={props.onOpenChange}>
        ... some other code ...
    </Drawer>
  );
}

export default function FormHome() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
     <Form {...form}>
        <DrawerWrapper open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen} />
     </Form>
  );
}
```

Still though, if your child component has a lot of code, I'd recommend to create a separate file for it, and then import it.

Comment: that's what I was looking for. So basically with props it automatically pass the parameters to my component?

Comment: @NicoCaldo, I wouldn't say "automatically", as you dynamically set and pass them in your jsx - `<DrawerWrapper open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen} />`, the `open` and `onOpenChange` properties are going to be passed as props. please refer to the documentation for more information: https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-props-to-a-component